# Can't get socket.io and nodejs running with OpenShift

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, openshift

I can't get socket.io running on OpenShift. I googled for some hours now but nothing really helped me. Locally it works fine (with different ports and localhost as host of course).

This is my server.js file:

```
var port      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
var ipadr = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
var http = require('http').createServer(function(request, response) {   
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end();
}).listen(port,ipadr);
console.log(port+":"+ipadr);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(http),
fs = require('fs'),
request = require('request'),
mysql = require('mysql'),
moment = require('moment'),
connectionsArray = [],
connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'xxx',
user: 'xxx',
password: 'xxx',
database: 'xxx',
port: 3306
}),
POLLING_INTERVAL = 1000,
pollingTimer;

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

var updateSockets = function(data) {
    // adding the time of the last update
    t = new Date();
    t = moment().format('H:mm:ss');
    console.log('(%s) Connections: %s', t, connectionsArray.length);
    // sending new data to all the sockets connected
    connectionsArray.forEach(function(tmpSocket) {
    tmpSocket.volatile.emit('notification', data);
    });
};
console.log('server.js executed\n');
```

When I run this on SSH OpenShift it just shows the first console.log with my port and ipadress of OpenShift and the last line of my server.js code:

> server.js executed

and that's it. So I don't get the "**a user connected**" message like when I test it locally.

This is how I want to connect in my client-side .js-file:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://njs-uniqo.rhcloud.com:8080/');
```

Browser (Chrome) Console outputs:

```
> ?s=product&id=10:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx.rhcloud.com:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1430395459829-1.
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
> The response had HTTP status code 503.
```

If I change the port to 8080 on the client-side .js-file I get **ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT**:

```
GET http://xxx.rhcloud.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1430395346761-6 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use port 8000. It's what openshift forces for websockets.

```
 var socket = io.connect('http://yourapp.rhcloud.com:8000/',{'forceNew':true });
```

Port 8000 is for http and 8443 is for https

[Source](https://blog.openshift.com/paas-websockets/)

Comment: Then I get the the console message with "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested" as mentioned and quoted in my question.

Comment: I am hoping you have enabled cors. If not, do it.- http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: Yes, I have enabled cors. I tried to connect with the express module and without it (like in my code) but got the same result.

Comment: hmm, cors is always tricky. Try checking/posting issues on github. Also one suggestion is to use socket client lib as cdn from your openshift app.

Comment: Can you explain your last sentence more detailed please? Do you mean using this `<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>` in the html file?

Comment: It says `GET http://myapp.rhcloud.com/socket.io-1.3.5.js 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable)` then. But I ran the server with `forever server.js`

Comment: Thanks, you save my day! The tip "Port 8000 is for http and 8443 is for https" was the key :)

Answer (score 1):

You must edit `package.json`. Add...

```
"socket.io": "~0.9.16"
```

...under dependencies. The server then automatically downloads socket.io which is not present by default.